# Is there a way to find which user deleted a specific storage account in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We are using a single Azure subscription for several projects with several users. One of our storage accounts has been deleted recently. Is there a way to find out which user deleted this storage account?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to find out which user deleted this storage account?

If the storage account is deleted via Azure Portal (and not the old one), you can to find this information is by going through `Activity Logs` (formerly known as `Audit Logs`). These logs include all of the provisioning actions performed via the Azure Resource Manager, in addition to other actions that are related to managing Azure resources (for example, autoscaling).

Comment: I think they changed the name to "Activity log"

Comment: @shachar Thank you! Corrected my answer.

Comment: So 2 things: 1) Even if they are classic storage accounts, if they are deleted via new portal, you should see them in activity logs. 2) In case, they are deleted from the old portal, you can try by checking "Operation Logs" there.

Comment: Note that filtering by "Resource Type" helps narrow it down - you might have a lot of results.

Comment: I have 0 entries about creation or deleting any resource from periods i know i created and deleted resources, there is just useless garbage in the activity log :(